# Jersey + Spring + Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jersey

im trying to deploy application with Jersey/Spring/Hibernate and every time im trying to deploy its throwing this exception:

```
    SEVERE: Context initialization failed
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/hibernate/cache/CacheProvider;
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2570)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1903)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:372)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMerge
 ...
```

My spring configuration xml look like this:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="intellidom.reader"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/intellidom" />
    <property name="username" value="root" />
    <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.pool_size">0</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

When sessionFactory and transactionManager are commented deploy works fine. What is a problem in this code?

EDIT:
pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.intellidom</groupId>
<artifactId>IntelliDOM</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>IntelliDOM</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>

    <!--string parsing-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Hibernate-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.4.FINAL</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--MySQL-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Jersey-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>IntelliDOM</finalName>
</build>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for Hibernate 4 in Spring 3.0.5. You need to use Hibernate 3 or upgrade the Spring version. Your pom.xml says you are using Hibernate 4, but the xml configuration is for Hibernate 3.
I believe support for Hibernate 4 has been introduced first time in Spring 3.1.0. So, either change your pom.xml to use either Hibernate 3 and Spring 3.0.5 or Hibernate 4 and at least Spring 3.1.0 and change all your packages to `hibernate4` instead of `hibernate3` in your xml config files, for example: `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean`